# Comparing more than 2 lists' elements in prolog to find if exactly two elements are the same

Tags: prolog

Each list represents a customer and his car brand and colour:

```
customer([_Name,_Surname,_Car,_Color]).
```

I would like to know if I can check in more than 2 lists that no customers have the same car of the same color. Because each customer has different name and surname from the others, (meaning that only _Car and _Color can take the same values in lists), I think one way is to check that the lists have not exactly 2 same elements. 
An example of lists is:

```
customer1([john,brown,vw,black]).
customer2([will,smith,audi,green]).
customer3([nick,cave,bmw,blue]).
customer4([jim,beam,bmw,black]).
```

In this example none has the same brand and the same color, so it's true.

What I imagine is something like:

```
result:-customer1(X1,Y1,Z1,W1), 
customer2(X2,Y2,Z2,W2), 
customer3(X3,Y3,Z3,W3),
customer4(X4,Y4,Z4,W4),
(check that no Z's AND W's are the same).
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why does each customer have its own predicate?  How do you identify who all of the customers are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this query would answer about different persons having the same Car of same Color:

```
?- customer([Name1,Surname1,Car,Color]), customer([Name2,Surname2,Car,Color]), ( Name1 \= Name2 ; Surname1 \= Surname2).
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there is also a solution if there were different lists for the information, like:     

    customer([john,brown]).
    customer([will,smith]).
    customer([nick,cave]).
    customer([jim,beam]).  

    car(vw).
    car(audi).
    car(bmw).  

    color(black).
    color(green).
    color(blue).  

And we had owners, like:     

    owner([customer,car,color]).

Comment: Basically, it's the same, just use a more generic pattern to match a car description: `?- customer([Name1,Surname1|CarDesc]),customer([Name2,Surname2|CarDesc]), etc...`

Answer (score 2):

This will tell you if two lists share the same car & color:

```
sameCarAndColor( [_,_,Car,Color], [_,_,Car,Color] ).
```

To check more than 2, just use this on each possible pair of lists.